# How to still run a step spring batch even when an exception occurs

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch program where execution flows of various steps are defined via xml files. One of these xml files is structured something like this.

```
<step id="step1" next="step2">
    <!-- Configuration of step 1 -->
</step>

<step id="step2" next="step3">
    <!-- Configuration of step 2 -->
</step>

<step id="step3" next="step4">
    <!-- Configuration of step 3 -->
</step>

<step id="step4" next="step5">
    <!-- Configuration of step 4 -->
</step>

<step id="step5" next="step6">
    <!-- Configuration of step 5 -->
</step>

<step id="step6" next="step7">
    <!-- Configuration of step 6 -->
</step>

<step id="step7" next="step8">
    <!-- Configuration of step 7 -->
</step>

<step id="step8">
    <!-- Configuration of step 8 -->
</step>
```

One of the last steps, let's say step 7, is a step that should always be performed, even if one of the previous steps fails, as it takes care of deleting temporary files that were generated during the execution of the flow. At the moment, when one of steps 1 to 6 generates an exception, step 7 is not reached, so the files to be deleted have to be deleted manually. I should make sure that step 7 is executed both when all the previous steps succeed and when one of them generates an exception that stops the program. Step 8, on the other hand, should be executed only when none of the previous steps generates an exception.
Searching the web, it seems that it is conceivable to use listeners to achieve the desired behavior, but I would like to understand how to configure it for the purpose or if there are other more suitable ways.

Comment: Listeners is what you want, a job listener would do the trick. Trying to shoehorn this into steps will only make it more difficult.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have replaced the delete step with a listeners but, although the related method is the last to be executed, its properties are not valued.

Comment: Let me guess you are doing a `new MyLIstener()` in your `Job` configuration method instead of having an `@Bean` method for the listener?

Comment: In the xml file that defines the job flow, I replaced the file deletion step with a listener. The class of this listener implements a JobExecutionListener. In the afterJob() method, I placed the instructions that delete the temporary directory. These instructions make use of injected variables, but they are not valued, whereas in the tasklet they were valued. Just as was done in the step, in the listener I added the properties like this
 <property name="propertyName" value="propertyValue" /> 
I also tried adding a bean in the applicationContext.xml, but the properties are still null.

Comment: @M.Deinum Finally, I also tried defining the variables in the class that implements the JobExecutionListener as static, but they keep getting null.

Comment: I'm lost as to what you did and tried. THe fact that your listener doesn't work is a different question and is not something we should try to answer here or discuss in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is only to delete temporary files created by steps no matter the exit status of those steps is, then a `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` is a good option. This listener is always executed.

However, if you want to introduce a complex flow of execution with conditional/branching like `step 7, is a step that should always be performed, even if one of the previous steps fails` or `Step 8, on the other hand, should be executed only when none of the previous steps generates an exception`, then you need to define a job execution `Flow`, as described in this section: [Controlling Step Flow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#controllingStepFlow)

Comment: In the xml file that defines the job flow, I replaced the file deletion step with a listener. The class of this listener implements a JobExecutionListener. In the afterJob() method, I placed the instructions that delete the temporary directory. These instructions make use of injected variables, but they are not valued, whereas in the tasklet they were valued.
Just as was done in the step, in the listener I added the properties like this
<property name="propertyName" value="propertyValue" />
I also tried adding a bean in the applicationContext.xml, but the properties are still null.

Comment: However, I confirm that the afterJob() method is the last to be executed. I inserted some debug prints and they are the last messages to appear in the logs.